# Not able to send or trace Dtmf from Android Device to sever using Andriod native sipstack?

Tags: android, sip, dtmf

I have implemented a simple sip call in Android App using Andriod native sipstack SipManager. But not able to send a dtmf signal. Its not received at server side and do not get any error as well. Not able to trace  what are error . i am technically makeing a sip call and while call trying to send two dtmf signal. Those signal doesnt receive at other site and even cannot trace the error as well.

There are some question related to my doubt here , but couldnt find any answer

```
public void sendDtmf(int code) {
    call.sendDtmf(code);
}


fab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            sendDtmf1(4);
            Log.e("$$", " 007-pressed");


        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            sendDtmf2(5);
            Log.e("$$", "007-released");

        }

        return true;
    }

});
```

Comment: There's a few ways to send DTMF over SIP, if it's sent in band you won't see anything in the SIP traces at the other end. Are you seeing the log entries in your debug to denote "007-pressed" and "007-released"?

Comment: is there any feature in sipManager to receive dtmf